# How to visualize joins between inner queries to their respective outer queries?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, join, subquery, exists

I seem to always have trouble visualizing what the meaning is when an inner query is joined to it's outer query.

Here's an example:

```
SELECT NM.MovieId, NM.MovieTitle
FROM NinjaMovies AS NM
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT TOP 1
    FROM Ninjas AS N
    INNER JOIN NinjaWeapons AS NW
        ON N.WeaponId = NW.WeaponId
    WHERE N.NinjaId = NM.NinjaId
)
```

Is there a way to represent this (or a similar kind of inner query joined to outer query) in a table or diagram of sorts?

Answer (score 1):

Just break it down into stages and consider what the output of each stage represents

```
SELECT *
FROM Ninjas AS N
INNER JOIN NinjaWeapons AS NW
    ON N.WeaponId = NW.WeaponId
```

This can be thought of as "all ninjas with at least one weapon along with their weapons". The data model does not appear to tie weapons to particular movies.

So you are now left with the simpler query to analyse (there is no value in including `TOP 1` in an `EXISTS` so that has also been removed.)

```
SELECT NM.MovieId, NM.MovieTitle
FROM NinjaMovies AS NM
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM WeaponOwningNinjasWithTheirWeapons AS N
    WHERE N.NinjaId = NM.NinjaId
)
```

There seems to be a normalisation issue here as apparently `NinjaMovies` will contain multiple rows for the same movie starring more than one Ninja and repeats the title in each one - but perhaps `NinjaMovies` is itself a view resulting from a join of normalised tables.

In any event `SELECT NM.MovieId, NM.MovieTitle` clearly selects the Movie Ids and Title from it so the only thing left to analyse is the `EXISTS`.

This simply says to only return rows where the corresponding Ninja exists in the `WeaponOwningNinjasWithTheirWeapons` result set.

So to sum up. The query returns all rows in `NinjaMovies` where the corresponding Ninja has at least one weapon.

The semantics of the query seem a bit odd as `NM.NinjaId` is not projected so in the event that the movie stars multiple ninjas - some with weapons and some without - there is no indication as to which led to the inclusion of the row. If you don't care about this then you should probably add a `DISTINCT` to remove duplicates in the event that the movie stars multiple weapon bearing ninjas.

Answer (score 0):

An equivalent query:

```
SELECT NM.MovieId, 
       NM.MovieTitle
FROM NinjaMovies        AS NM
INNER JOIN Ninjas       AS N 
    ON N.NinjaId  = NM.NinjaId
INNER JOIN NinjaWeapons AS NW 
    ON N.WeaponId = NW.WeaponId
```

Answer (score -1):

This is helpful to me: also thinking of joins as putting two tables together side by side, whereas something like a union is more like adding one table to the bottom of another table(I say table but it's really your result set).

[image]

Answer (score -2):

In the past I have utilised [Venn Diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram). I will try and post a sample later.